# vmware virtual appliance hosting (preferably in the UK)

Tags: virtualization, hosting, virtual-appliances

I am looking for a provider of vmware virtual appliance hosting preferably in the UK.  Here are my criteria:-

1. Must either offer or allow the install of the Brightmail Security Gateway Virtual appliance - (http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/va/83603).
2. Must offer a VPS package which meets minimum specification for the Brightmail Security Gateway Virtual appliance, notably 2GB RAM.
3. Must be able to rent out 2 VPS'es at not much more than £50 each per month on a one month notice contract.
4. Preferably reasonably established hosting provider.
5. Preferably has a vmware certification.

Does anyone know of a match?

EDIT: The only provider I have found is www.vmhosts.co.uk.  Are there any others??

Comment: Closing as this is a shopping question, and thus off-topic for all Stack Exchange sites

Answer (score 1):

Most VPS hosting companies use XEN because it has a lower total cost, and because VMWARE is not very hosting-company friendly. Brightmail should work just fine on XEN but Symantec don't want to support it on XEN because their people don't know anything about it.

Therefore, you will not find very many options. I would suggest that you also look at sites on the continent, for instance Amsterdam is not that far away and has a lot of hosting and excellent network connectivity.

For instance, [LeaseWeb](http://www.leaseweb.com/en/vps) in Amsterdam do vmware hosting.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hosting365.com/ offer this service, are VMware partners, and deliver services on a highly redundant 'cloud' platform running VMware and IBM SVC (on the storage side).

Complete with enterprise level SLA's, 24/7 direct support, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I have emailed them, I couldn't find anything about uploading images/virtual appliances on their website though.